# Quasi polynomial algorithm for np complete problem

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, p-vs-np

I know that quasi polynomial algorithm is neither polynomial nor exponential. But I want to know if we find such algorithm for NP complete problem, will it be of any use? Or is there such algorithm exists already?

I want to know why it becomes impossible to solve NP complete problems on regular machine. Is it because it will take longer time to solve? (Maybe in years) Or just because it's taking exponential time? So if we find quasi polynomial algorithm, then also it will take years to solve NP complete problem or will it take less time and have practical applications in real life even it's not polynomial time? Also does a quasi polynomial algorithm imply that P=NP?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/167293/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/467758/37212. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You got helpful feedback and useful information on Math Overflow.  That feedback is not reflected in your post here.  That can be considered impolite, as it can be viewed as wasting the time of people here.  If you post on the wrong site, please delete it before posting elsewhere, and please incorporate the feedback you've received before posting elsewhere, including studying up on the resources/links that others have suggested.  This site is not a personal help desk -- it is a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge, and we want to help others in the future.

Comment: @D.W. I'd say the problem is not the crosspost — the crosspost was appropriate once the question got closed on MathOverflow (which it did). The essence of the question is appropriate here. The problem is that the poster just lazily copied the question *exactly as they had written it* on MO, with zero attempt at improving it or even reformulating it, despite the pointers they had received on MO (to the ”Exponential Time Hypothesis” article on Wikipedia and to similar better-worded and well-received questions on CSTheory-SE).

Comment: So, copying the links suggested on MathOverflow, the similar questions on CSTheory-SE are [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21571/17747) and [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47653/17747). I should probably add [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38473/17747) as well.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, The question was cross-posted here before it was closed on MO.  It was posted on MO on 3/26, cross-posted here on 3/27, then closed on MO on 3/28.  So I think there were two problems: (a) cross-posting (before it was closed), (b) copying the question without addressing the feedback already received on MO.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition given. Assume you have a quasi-polynomial algorithm that takes $2^{(\log n)^{1.1}}$ nanoseconds. This is less than if $n^2$ nanoseconds $ n \le 2 ^ { 2 ^ {10}} = 2^{1024}$. That will be solvable for quite large x. But with large c the function grows much faster. With c = 2 the same expression becomes $n^ {\log n } $ which grows faster than $ n^{10}$ if n >= 1,024. Every time n doubles, the exponent increases by 1.

So c = 1.1 would make typical cryptographical problems laughably easy. c = 2 would make some solvable, with a very very powerful computer. Probably could be handled by switching from 1024 to 4096 bits. You can do the maths for c = 3. I think current cryptography would be safe.

In the end, it is not NP-completeness that makes crypto safe. It’s the fact that there are no known algorithms that crack crypto in more than a negligible number of cases in an acceptable amount of time. I could easily design an NP-complete problem where 99% of cases are solved easily; that would be useless for crypto.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that quasi-polynomial-time algorithms have a running time upperbounded by $2^{O((\log{n})^c)}$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{N}$. It has a separate complexity class **QP**.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial_time):

> The decision problems with quasi-polynomial time algorithms are natural candidates for being NP-intermediate, neither having polynomial time nor likely to be NP-hard.

Thus, finding a problem in **QP** that does not belong to **P** will prove **P $\ne$ NP**.

Typically, **NP-Complete** problems do not expect to have polynomial time algorithms. They typically have an exponential running time. For large input sizes, it will take significantly long time to terminate.

Comment: How quasi polynomial algorithm will impact cryptography and other np complete problems? Please explain

Comment: Please refer to a book on computational complexity! There, you will find plenty of theorems and open conjectures. Also, you will get to know how showing the existence/absence of certain types of problems causes different complexity classes to collapse or make them disjoint.

Comment: You wrote: finding a problem in QP that does not belong to P will prove P ≠ NP. Please explain how ?

Comment: We will then have a **NP-intermediate** problem making **P $\ne$ NP**. Please read the definitions first. Do the hard work on your own first. This place is not your handy chatGPT prompt :)

Comment: @codeR It’s less polite but much more intelligent:-)